# Alternatives for "based on"

Tags: phrase-request, alternatives

In many sentences like the following I use "based on" to relate something to another thing. Are there alternatives for "based on"? for example other ways to state the following sentences?

> A dialogue opens in which he can select the distinguishing properties of the anchor **based on** its text or a pattern in the text
>
> In our approach we try to simulate how a user finds the desired data by scanning and blocking the page **based on** semantic delimiters
>
> Ideally, anchors are established **based on** the content of data item.
>
> Besides the primitive variables which provide primary contexts **based on** the anchor nodes, we can build new contexts over them by employing set operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `derives from` as an alternative of `based on`.

> A dialogue opens in which he can select the distinguishing properties of the anchor **derives from** its text or a pattern in the text

Comment: drives from or drived from?!

Comment: Both are correct.